# Resize GIF animation, pil/imagemagick, python

Tags: python, imagemagick, python-imaging-library, gif, pythonmagick

I want to change size of GIF animation image using python and PIL or PythonMagick. I can't find solution. PIL and thumbnail method works for jpg and png but not for gif. ImageMagick has command mogrify/convert -resize '1280x1024>' but i can't find documentation and i don't know how to do it with pythonmagick.

Anyone knows solution?

In the worst case i use os/subprocess and convert ;-S

Thanks.

Comment: I'd recomment that you do just that in the meantime - use subprocess and convert. Pythonmagic suffers from this lack of proper maintenance - and PIL just supports reading animated GIFs, nothing else. Leave the question open - it maybe that someone with a psnipped to do the resize with Pythonmagic shows up.

Answer (score 13):

You can use PIL and `images2gif`, a short PIL based module linked to on this [blog page](http://www.somethinkodd.com/oddthinking/2005/12/06/python-imaging-library-pil-and-animated-gifs/), and available [here](https://github.com/almarklein/visvis/blob/65144bee561a28e37359a6604aafb3cd8b462823/vvmovie/images2gif.py). Code used to process this `rose.gif` is below. I set the `images2gif.readGif` 'read as numpy array' property to `false` in order to get a list of PIL images so as I could use the PIL `thumbnail` function.

Orignial: [image: rose] Processed: [image: small rose]

```
import Image
import images2gif

frames = images2gif.readGif("rose.gif",False)
for frame in frames:
    frame.thumbnail((100,100), Image.ANTIALIAS)

images2gif.writeGif('rose99.gif', frames)
```

I'm not sure how to preserve transparency, my attempts to do so have failed (so far).

Comment: According to http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t354000-pil-and-transparent-gifs.html, you have to handle transparency yourself, with transparency = im.info["transparency"]; ...; out.save("out.gif", transparency=transparency)

Answer (score 4):

Some amazing person made an updated version of images2gif.py that accounts for transparency:

https://bitbucket.org/bench/images2gif.py/overview

There are still some artifacts, but it's way better than the original!

Comment: Failed at first attempt - palettes list looks like [None, None.. None] and tries to write that into the new file. Sadly, that's what you're expected to happen when a piece of code doesn't come with tests. The original one at least gives a meaningful message: `RuntimeError: Cannot get palette. Maybe you should try imageio instead.`